# How to make breakpoints in Runnable() break in Android studio?

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-studio, breakpoints

I have checked quite a few related SO posts, but been unable to get I am looking for.  My question is very simple and straightforward.  Here is the code:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
            android.util.Log.d("Debug", "*****breakpoint******");
    }
}).start();
```

I have set a breakpoint at android.util.Log.d(), so I know it is executed, but it never breaks. Breakpoints in other places work fine.  I am running Android Studio 1.5.1 on Windows 10. I am using an emulator to do the test.

Could anyone offer a tip on this?

Per request, the following are screenshots of the code and logcat respectively:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you get the "*****breakpoint******" in logcat?Or can you add more code in it?

Comment: @tinysunlight Yes I do get "*****breakpoint******" in logcat, and this is why I was saying that I know it is executed.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the break point?

Comment: @tinysunlight I have just added two screenshots per your request.

Comment: When is the Runnable executed? Is it very soon after the app starts? I reported a [bug about missing early breakpoints](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201427), apparently caused by a race condition with connecting the debugger. Maybe try my workaround: add a 1s sleep before your breakpoint and see if it's hit more reliably?

Answer (score 0):

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config1
            debuggable false
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have just taken a look at the breakpoint.  The configuration is identical to what you show.

Comment: I have just tried it, but it still does not work.  I have just tried a quite different emulator, the problem remains.

Comment: Actually there are a few more lines of code following android.util.Log.d(...), and I have set all of them as breakpoints.  None of them have worked.  I really appreciate your trying to lend a hand here.

Comment: I have just realized that this happens with the release build, not debug build.

Comment: In release build, all breakpoints will not work only if you turn debuggable to true.

Comment: How come breakpoints outside new Thread(...) work fine with the release build.  Another interesting thing is that if I wrap the code into a method of the activity, then the breakpoints will work. It seems that they stop working only if the are in run(){}.  I am lost.